# Bitbucket Cloud interceptor for Tekton EventListener

Tags: bitbucket, webhooks, bitbucket-cloud, tekton, tekton-pipelines

I'm creating an eventlisterner for my repo on Bitbucket Cloud and saw on the curent example on the Tekton documentation that the Bitbucket interceptor only support Bitbucket Server.
I've created the eventlistener and looks like this:

```
---
apiVersion: triggers.tekton.dev/v1alpha1
kind: EventListener
metadata:
  name: bitbucket-el
spec:
  serviceAccountName: tekton-triggers-admin
  triggers:
    - name: bitbucket-triggers
      interceptors:
        - bitbucket:
            secretRef:
              secretName: bitbucket-secret
              secretKey: secretToken
            eventTypes:
        - cel:
            filter: "header.match('X-Event-Key', 'repo:push')"
            overlays:
              - key: extensions.tag_name
                expression: "split(body.ref, '/')[2]"
              - key: extensions.mangledtag
                expression: "split(split(body.ref, '/')[2], '.')[0]+'-'+split(split(body.ref, '/')[2], '.')[1]+'-'+split(split(body.ref, '/')[2], '.')[2]"
      bindings:
        - ref: bitbucket-binding
      template:
        ref: bitbucket-template
```

and I pass it the token generated (bitbucket-secret) from Bitbucket Cloud consumer secret by going through this doc: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-oauth-on-bitbucket-cloud/

I used basic auth on Ingress and the webhook return 401 Unauthorized and now after I remove the basic auth and then trigger the webhook with a push I'm seeing `403 Forbiden`.

Check the image below for illustartion:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjW0s.png)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I spend alot of time on this issue and finally fixed it by using the CEL expression interceptors, as follows.

In this Trigger, we are using the overlays to add the "X-Hub-Signature" to the body of the payload, where the expression value i.e., 1234567 doesn't matter it can be anything, we are just adding the HMAC to the body so that we will not get an error.

Note: By default, there is no interceptor for the bitbucket CLOUD

```
apiVersion: triggers.tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Trigger
metadata:
name: energy
spec:
serviceAccountName: pipeline
interceptors:
- ref:
name: "cel"
params:
- name: "filter"
value: "header.match('X-Event-Key', 'repo:push')"
- name: "overlays"
value:
- key: X-Hub-Signature
expression: "1234567"
bindings:
- ref: energy
template:
ref: energy
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to achieve the same, starting a build when a PR merge has been done in BitBucket cloud.

I was able to create the EventListener resource, but my pipeline is not triggered after merging a PR.

Looking at your example, I still have some questions

- How is the GIT repository and the secret configured?
- How can you specify a specific branch?

I was looking for a complete example but it seems like Tekton is just ignoring Bitbucket Cloud as a VCS ...

Kind regards,

Bregt

Comment: Have you checked your EventListener pod logs? When events from CVS don't trigger anything, that's the first place to look at: did your EL receive something? What did it do, is it complaining about something?

Comment: Most important lines


    {"level":"info","ts":"2022-08-26T14:41:12.488Z","caller":"logging/config.go:79","msg":"Fetch GitHub commit ID from kodata failed","error":"open /var/run/ko/HEAD: no such file or directory"}
    {"level":"warn","ts":"2022-08-26T14:41:12.489Z","logger":"eventlistener","caller":"v2/config.go:178","msg":"Sink timeout configuration is invalid, default to -1 (no timeout)"}
     {"level":"debug","ts":"2022-08-26T14:41:13.509Z","logger":"eventlistener","caller":"adapter/adapter.go:87","msg":"Creating event broadcaster"}


This actually is the last line ...